# Trying to join certain values in different tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i'm very new to mysql and I am trying to create a database that can store users emails and passwords on one table and the values they input on another table, how do I join the tables to make sure that the inputted values are linked to the correct user. This is the code I've been using but it won't allow the value to be stored while the foreign key is run, but if I remove the foreign key I can store the value. Please help.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`)
)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gluco` (
  `G_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bloods` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `data`(`use_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `G_id_UNIQUE` (`G_id`)
)


<?php
include('db.php'); 

if (!isset($_POST['reading'])) { //checking if user has entered this page directly
    include('contactus.php');
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['reading'])&&$_POST['reading']==""||!isset($_POST['reading'])) {
        $error[] = "fill in your blood/glucose"; 
    }

    $reading = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reading']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM gluco WHERE bloods  = '$reading'";

    if(isset($error)){
        if(is_array($error)){
            echo "<div class=\"error\"><span>please check the errors and refill the form<span><br/>";

            foreach ($error as $ers) {
                echo "<span>".$ers."</span><br/>";
            }

            echo "</div>";

            include('contactus.php');
        }
    }

    if(!isset($error)){
        $sreading=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reading']);
        $sip=mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        $save = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `gluco` ( `bloods`  )VALUES ('$sreading')");

        if($save){
            echo "<div class=\"success\"><span>Your reading has been successfully stored</span><br/></div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class=\"warning\"><span>Some Error occured during processing your data</div>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES data(use_id),` shouldn't that be `user_id`

Comment: Thanks flungo, I've been looking at it so long I've begun to stop seeing such silly mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct in its logic. But theres an error on the referenced column name:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`)
)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gluco` (
  `G_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bloods` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `data`(`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `G_id_UNIQUE` (`G_id`)
)
```

and on this line:

```
$save = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `gluco` ( `bloods`  )VALUES ('$sreading')");
```

you are not setting the user_id in your insert statement, so, the foreign key will not work and the insert will not be made. So, you'll need to have the user id stored in a variable (since i don't know the context and the scope in the code, i can't help you setting this variable). So, your code should be like that:

```
$save = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gluco (bloods, user_id)VALUES ('$sreading', $user_id)");
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, I've corrected that but still getting the same result. Beginning to think it must be my PHP instead.

Comment: I've added it above, when I try to add values I get "Some Error occured during processing your data".

Comment: Hi Andre, I seem to have had a few problems uploading the php.

Comment: please see my answer again

Comment: Hi Andre, as I said I'm very new to this and not quite sure where to insert user_id and what naming to use.

Comment: Thanks for everything Andre, it's good to know that there are people willing to help and share their knowledge. Your solution was perfect when combined with a SESSION. Thanks again. Chris 'Crix' Madine.

Comment: well, if you're grateful, please accept my answer ;) hahah

Comment: Sorry Andre, I'm new to all of this.